# Jest with Apollo Client - Testing React App with calling useQuery inside react hooks context

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, apollo-client, react-test-renderer

I have a problem on testing react hooks app with Jest and React-test-renderer. The problem defined when I put useQuery inside of react hooks context file.

I had a similar files following this apollo docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/ but only different in calling useQuery in react hooks context file.

**CatContext.js**

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';
import { GET_ALL_CATS } from 'graphqlquery/Queries';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

export const CatContext = createContext();

export default function CatContextProvider(props) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_CATS);
        
    return (
        <CatContext.Provider value={{loading,error,data}}>
            {props.children}
        </CatContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```
export function CatList() {
    const {loading,error,data} = useContext(CatContext);
    if(loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if(error) return <div>Error...</div>;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                    {data.cat.name} is a {data.cat.breed}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import { CatList } from 'components/CatList';
import { GET_ALL_CATS } from 'graphqlquery/Queries';

const mocks = [
    {
      request: {
        query: GET_ALL_CATS,
      },
      result: {
        data: {
            cat: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' },
        }
      }
    }
  ]

  it('renders without error', () => {
    const component = TestRenderer.create(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <CatList  />
      </MockedProvider>,
    );
  
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree.children).toContain('Loading...');
  });
```

The problem doesn't exists if I call useQuery in `App.js`, but when I call useQuery inside `CatContext`, it provides an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined.`

Any thought why this `loading` of useQuery that I call from `CatContext.js` is undefined? and how to fix it?